# MyBatis passing null parameter to procedure

Tags: java, mybatis

How can we pass null parameters to stored procedures with MyBatis 3?

I'm trying to do in XML something like this:

```
{ call PRC_FOO(#{parameter1, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},

               #{parameter2, mode=IN, jdbcType=NULL})}
```

But, for some reason, doesn't work for me.

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'parameter2' not found. Available parameters are [parameter1, param1]
```